# Monk in nodejs sometimes returns null on findAndModify

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I have some strange error that I don't know how to treat or how to manage.

The problem is that sometimes when when I try to update a field with the function findAndModify it returns me null.

I tried to debug and looks like both of the request are the same, just diferent result.

```
//THIS NOT

{ database: 'testdb',
  collection: 'mytable',
  query: { _id: 5612454f228bd5b7428b456a },
  update: { '$inc': { int_lastid: 1 } },
  options: 
   { new: true,
     fields: {},
     safe: true,
     connection: 
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socketOptions: [Object],
        id: 0,
        connected: true,
        domainSocket: false,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 3,
        maxBsonSize: 16777216,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
        maxNumberOfDocsInBatch: 2000,
        buffer: null,
        sizeOfMessage: 0,
        bytesRead: 0,
        stubBuffer: null,
        eventHandlers: [Object],
        maxBsonSettings: [Object],
        socketTimeoutMS: [Getter/Setter],
        logger: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        writeSteam: [Object],
        maxWriteBatchSize: 1000,
        serverCapabilities: [Object] },
     serializeFunctions: false,
     checkKeys: false } }



//THIS OK
{ database: 'testdb',
  collection: 'mytable',
  query: { _id: 5612454f228bd5b7428b456a },
  update: { '$inc': { int_lastid: 1 } },
  options: 
   { new: true,
     fields: {},
     safe: true,
     connection: 
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socketOptions: [Object],
        id: 0,
        connected: true,
        domainSocket: false,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 3,
        maxBsonSize: 16777216,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
        maxNumberOfDocsInBatch: 2000,
        buffer: null,
        sizeOfMessage: 0,
        bytesRead: 0,
        stubBuffer: null,
        eventHandlers: [Object],
        maxBsonSettings: [Object],
        socketTimeoutMS: [Getter/Setter],
        logger: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        writeSteam: [Object],
        maxWriteBatchSize: 1000,
        serverCapabilities: [Object] },
     serializeFunctions: false,
     checkKeys: false } }
```

Too many request can affect the result?

My code is the next one

```
        app.post('/findAndModify', function(req,res){
        res.append('Content-Type','application/json');
        if(req.body == undefined){
            res.status(400);
            res.json({"status":400,"message":"Bad request."});
            res.end();
            return;
        }
        if(req.body.database == undefined || req.body.collection == undefined || req.body.query == undefined, req.body.update == undefined){
            res.status(400);
            res.json({"status":400,"message":"Bad request."});
            console.log(req.body);
            res.end();
            return;
        }
        _database = req.body.database;
        _collection = req.body.collection;
        _query = req.body.query;
        _update = req.body.update;
        _options = {};
        if(req.body.options != undefined)
            _options = req.body.options;
        //console.log(_options);
        db = req.mongo.getConnection(_database);
        collection.findAndModify(
            {
                "query":_query,
                "update": _update,

            },_options,function(err,doc){
                if(err)
                { 
                    res.status(500);
                    res.json({"status":500, "message":err});
                    res.end();
                }
                else{
                    res.status(200);
                    if(doc == null){
                        console.log("//THIS NOT");
                        console.log(util.inspect(req.body));
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("//THIS OK");
                        console.log(util.inspect(req.body));
                    }
                    res.json(doc);
                    res.end();
                }
            }
          );

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference at the options object and the second request is not valid. My assumption is that it ignores that option and sets it to it's default value (false). You can read more about this [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#return-data).

```
options: 
   { new: true}
     fields: {},
     ...
   }
```

Do you have an error message or the problem is that strange behavior?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault when i copied and paste the result, the extra } was added by me after the print, It should not be there.

Comment: Oh, right. Have you tried another request (find, for example) with the same data? It's gonna be easier to debug if you split the operations to see what is going on. And possible solution I see there is to use $set operator in your update query - "update": { $set: _update }. I'm not sure this will solve the problem, but it's a common "issue-solver" with findAndModify() in Monk.